# Cassandra throws unknown error while creating column family through CLI or Astayanx client

Tags: cassandra, thrift, astyanax

I am trying to use chunked object store of cassandra and when I am trying to create compatible column family for the same, using CLI or Astyanax client, it throws this error:

```
INFO 12:26:31,175 Create new ColumnFamily: org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@321f321f[cfId=1000,ksName=TESTKEYSPACE1,cfName=updatedstorage,cfType=Standard,
comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,subcolumncomparator=<null>,comment=,readRepairChance=0.1,dclocalReadRepairChance=0.0,replicateOnWrite=true,gc
GraceSeconds=864000,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxC
ompactionThreshold=32,keyAlias=<null>,columnAliases=[],valueAlias=<null>,column_metadata={},compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.Size
TieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionOptions={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor},bloomFilterFpCha
nce=<null>,caching=KEYS_ONLY]
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 ExceptionCode=c0000005 ExceptionAddress=01372DED ContextFlags=0001007f
Handler1=00259A50 Handler2=003C95C0 InaccessibleAddress=000000B4
EDI=00000080 ESI=45F2A04A EAX=00000022 EBX=45E5A300
ECX=46B34830 EDX=00000080
EIP=01372DED ESP=46B347C4 EBP=46174800 EFLAGS=00010206
Module=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\jclscar_24.dll
Module_base_address=01340000 Offset_in_DLL=00032ded
Target=2_40_20080816_022093_lHdSMr (Windows Vista 6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1)
CPU=x86 (4 logical CPUs) (0xf88ee000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
sun_misc_Unsafe_getLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2J:0x01372DED [0x01372DB0 +0x0000003D]
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" - please wait.
JVMDUMP007I JVM Requesting System dump using 'C:\cassandra\apache-cassandra-1.1.7\bin\core.20130204.122631.9232.0001.dmp'
```

My CLI command is:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY updatedstorage WITH comparator = UTF8Type AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```

Astayanax code is:

```
keyspace.createColumnFamily(CF_STANDARD1, ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                .put("default_validation_class", "UTF8Type")
                .put("key_validation_class", "UTF8Type")
                .put("comparator_type", "UTF8Type")
                .build());
```

Cassandra version: 1.1.7

Could you please help understanding what is the problem, everytime I run it, it goes to JVM dump ... :(

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: 1.6 is the jdk version